# Students can't install Extensions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: active-directory, mount, samba4, dotnet-framework

We are a school and would like to use Visual Studio Code together with the Omnisharp extension.

The students' working environment has the following characteristics
Server-stored home directories

- Active Directory environment Samba 4.x is used as Active Directory
- domain controller Students do not have write access to C:\
- Extensions are provided locally as a .vsix file
- Access to the Marketplace is not permitted
- --extensions-dir=H:\vscode\ext is used to redirect the extension directory to the student's server-stored home directory when starting
  Visual Studio Code.

Unfortunately, students can't install an extension (.vsix). The following error appears:

```
[2021-12-06 11:20:42.962] [renderer1] [error] ["Extract: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'H:\\vscode\\extensions\\.819a7632-05f1-4909-b81c-aaf7c669f02b\\.debugger\\cs'","    at s.extractAtLocation (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:188875)","    at async s.extractUserExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:185594)","    at async q.extract (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:198974)","    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:199612)"]
[2021-12-06 11:20:42.988] [renderer1] [error] EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'H:\vscode\extensions\.819a7632-05f1-4909-b81c-aaf7c669f02b\.debugger\cs': Extract: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'H:\vscode\extensions\.819a7632-05f1-4909-b81c-aaf7c669f02b\.debugger\cs'
    at s.extractAtLocation (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:188875)
    at async s.extractUserExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:185594)
    at async q.extract (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:198974)
    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:199612)
```

This behaviour cannot be easily reproduced in another active directory domain. Does anyone know anything about this error message?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably installed Visual Studio Code with **system installer mode**, or a **administrative mode**, instead of **user installer mode**, or **non administrative mode**. So students don't have access to the Program files folder to install addons. Reinstall Visual Studio Code so it installs in user's profile.

See [this](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=MERGETASKS) for further explanation.

You can use this silent install command:

```
VSCodeSetup.exe /VERYSILENT /MERGETASKS=!runcode /NORESTART /CURRENTUSER
```